# How to specify a RedirectToRouteResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My existing MVC code contains an action routine something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register1(SomeViewModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Register", new { p = model.PageNumber - 1 });
}
```

I want to move this code to a library routine:

```
public static ActionResult ProcessPost(Controller controller, string action,
                                       int pageNumber)
{
    // Redirect to the specified action on the specified controller
    return new RedirectToRouteResult( <something here> );
}
```

and call it from the action routine like this:

```
return ProcessPost(this, "register", model.PageNumber);
```

Can some kind person give me the `<something here>` code that yields an `ActionResult` that redirects to the specified action (specified by the string argument) on the specified Controller (specified by the Controller argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, this appears to be a simple solution:

```
return new RedirectResult(controller.Url.RouteUrl(
     new { action = action, p = pageNumber }
     ));
```

Apparently, the Url method on a specific Controller instance is smart enough to use that instance to get the controller name part of the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation on [RedirectToRouteResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) seems pretty straight forward:

```
var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
routeValues.Add("Action", action);
routeValues.Add("Controller", controller.GetType().Name);
routeValues.Add("PageNumber", pageNumber);
var result = new (RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out how to get the name of the controller for the route value out of the Controller instance.  It didn't occur to me to just use reflection to get the name.  (I was digging through all of the members exposed by Controller looking for a Name property.)  But I think I've come up with a simpler solution (see the answer I posted to my own question).